# Saving as 16-bit .raww ("Raw image format (Word)") in ImageJ or MATLAB to import to DaVis

Tags: image, matlab, 16-bit, imagej

I have a set of 32-bit TIFFs that form a volume dataset (i.e. a stack). Using ImageJ, I'm downsampling them to 16-bit and exporting them as a raw file. The intention is that they will then be imported into LaVision's DaVis to perform digital volume correlation.

The problem is that DaVis can only import 16-bit raw files correctly if they are in a format the software describes as ".RAWW (Raw image format(Word))". For 8-bit data, other import options are as .RAF (Raw float) or .RAW (RAw byte), but neither of these formats works with 16-bit data, as the image is corrupted when imported into DaVis. I've found no way of controlling the SaveAs raw setting in ImageJ, and no references to either ImageJ or MATLAB supporting saving as .RAWW, nor indeed any references to a .RAWW format online.

Can anyone suggest how I might either export a .RAWW, or convert a .RAW to .RAWW? If not, can anyone provide me with any information about the .RAWW format?

Solutions in ImageJ or MATLAB preferred, but anything would be helpful.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Did you ask LaVision's support? They should be able to tell you what's the right way to import 16-bit data.

Answer (score 0):

In their doc LaVision says:

- Supply non-segmented images.  We need the raw images with the full contrast info

  - Little endian (intel) byte order
- Please supply images as RAW volume images.

  - If you have TIF stacks, please use ImageJ to convert to RAW volume images before sending
- Please ensure volume RAW image file has appropriate extension

  - *.RAW (byte) : 8bit unsigned*
  - .RAWW (word) : 16bit unsigned
  - *.RAF (float) : 32bit real

My understanding is that you save your stack as a RAW image with the depth of your choice and rename the files according to your choice.

A firm answer would help me too, though.